# hive-HBase ClassNotFound happend when do mapreduce job

Tags: hive, hbase

I have a hive+hbase integration cluster.
I created a table by:
    CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) 
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
    TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");

it is ok when execute:
    select * from hbase_table_1;

but when I execute count operation, the classnotfound error will happen.
    select count(*) from hbase_table_1;

error info is:
    java.io.IOException:cannot find class
         at org.apache.............HiveInputformat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:220)
           ...........
    Caused by:java.lang.ClassNoteFoundException:
           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

those error message does not notice me which class.

Sorry for my poor English.

Any one encounter this issue?

Comment: I write the error message by hand. I cannot copy it from cluster machine because the permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) COPY THESE FILES TO THE HADOOP LIBRARY.

    sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.7.0-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/

    sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/

    sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/



    2)CLOSE HBASE AND HADOOP USING FOLLOWING COMMOND

    /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
    /usr/lib/hbase/bin/stop-hbase.sh

3) RESTART HBASE AND HADOOP USING COMMOND 
 /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Now create table in hive using Hbase storage handler.

Comment: @Suthar thank you. It solve my problem. Are there any way that no need restart the hbase and hadoop?  because in production environment.

Comment: Then don't perform the 2 and 3 step.may be solve your problem